# Como fazer leitura de itens de um array dentro de outro?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, array

Este é o meu array multidimensional:

```
<?php  
  $beneficiarios = array
        (


            array(

                "codigo_membro" =>$cod,
                "nome" => $_POST['nome1'],
                "n_identificacao" => $_POST['n_identificacao1'],
                "parentesco" => $_POST['parentesco1'],
                "telefone" => $_POST['telefone1'],
                "email" => $_POST['email1']
            ),
            array(
                "codigo_membro" => $cod,
                "nome" => $_POST['nome2'],
                "n_identificacao" => $_POST['n_identificacao2'],
                "telefone" => $_POST['telefone2'],
                "email" => $_POST['email2']
            )


        );

?>
```

Eu gostaria de ler os elementos dentro de cada array no array multidimensional.

Por exemplo: eu gostaria de poder imprimir o que está escrito 'nome' para cada array.

Acredito que talvez se aplique um laço de repetição, mas estou sem ideias
tentei:

```
<?php echo $beneficiarios[0][1]?>
```

Mas está a dar erro.

Comment: E assim: `<?php echo $beneficiarios[0]['nome']?>`?

Comment: https://ideone.com/LV5eu8

Comment: Muito grato...  Até aí funciona (ideone.com/LV5eu8 ), Mas eu gostaria de poder imprimir todas as informções de cada array mediante as posições dos mesmos..  desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

fiz alguns ajustes no neste código e conseguí obter o resultado. Gostaria de compartilhar. 
(código exemplo)

```html
    <?php

  $Array = array(
   array("Conta" => "FRANCIELE OLIVEIRA", "CPF" => "", "TelefoneRes"=> '(00) 0000-0000'),
   array("Conta" => "BEATRIX BEHN", "CPF" => "", "TelefoneRes"=> '(00) 0000-0')
                                                        );
$i = 0;
foreach ($Array as $result):
       $i++;
 extract($result);
 ?>
 <tr>
 <td class="text-left col-md-9 control-label"> <?php echo $Conta ?></td>
 <td class="text-left col-md-9 control-label"> <?php  echo $CPF ?></td>
 <td class="text-left col-md-9 control-label"> <?php echo $TelefoneRes ?></td>

</tr>
    <?php
endforeach;
               ?>
```

Desde já agradeço a atenção dispensada.